# Why will a rake file used to seed a datbase not work due to foreign key constraints in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, activerecord

I have created a dummy travel agency with Rails 6 and I  am trying to use a rake file to seed data for ships, crusies and customer details etc.

The file: `ships.rake` looks like this:

```
namespace :ships do
  desc "TODO"
  task seed_cabins: :environment do
    CreditCard.destroy_all
    Address.destroy_all
    Customer.destroy_all
    Cruise.destroy_all
    Ship.destroy_all

    p "tables emptied"
  
    5.times do |index|
      Ship.create!(name: Faker::Coffee.blend_name, tonnage: Faker::Number.within(range: 10000..100000))
    end

    p "ships created"
    
    # create cabins for each ship
    ships = Ship.all
    ships.each do |ship|
      5.times do |index|
        Cabin.create!(
          ship_id: ship.id,
          name: "Suite #{index+1}",
          beds: Faker::Number.between(from: 1, to: 3),
          deck: Faker::Number.between(from: 1, to: 3)
        )
      end
    end
    
    p "Cabins created"
    ships = Ship.all
    ships.each do |ship|
      2.times do |index|
        Cruise.create!(
          ship_id: ship.id,
          name: Faker::Hacker.adjective.capitalize + " " +Faker::Hacker.noun.capitalize+" Cruise"
        )
      end
    end
    
  #create customers
    3.times do |index |
      Customer.create!(
        first_name:Faker::Name.first_name,
        last_name:Faker::Name.last_name,
       has_good_credit: true,
        paid: false
      )
    end

   #give each customer an addresses and credit card
    customers = Customer.all
    customers.each do | customer|
      Address.create!(
      street:Faker::Address.street_address,
      city:Faker::Address.city,
      postcode:Faker::Address.postcode,
      customer_id: customer.id
      )
      year = [2020, 2021,2022, 2023]
      organisations =["American Express", "MasterCard", "Visa"]
      CreditCard.create!(
        customer_id:customer.id,
        number:Faker::Number.number(12),
        exp_date:year.sample.to_s + "/" + Faker::Number.between(1,12).to_s,
       name_on_card: customer.first_name + " " + customer.last_name,
       organisation: organisations.sample.to_s
      )
    end
    p "customers created"
  end
end
```

The database schema looks like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_10_27_221059) do

  create_table "addresses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "street"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "postcode"
    t.integer "customer_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["customer_id"], name: "index_addresses_on_customer_id"
  end

  create_table "cabins", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "beds"
    t.integer "deck"
    t.integer "ship_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["ship_id"], name: "index_cabins_on_ship_id"
  end

  create_table "credit_cards", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "number"
    t.string "exp_date"
    t.string "name_on_card"
    t.string "organisation"
    t.integer "customer_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["customer_id"], name: "index_credit_cards_on_customer_id"
  end

  create_table "cruises", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "ship_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["ship_id"], name: "index_cruises_on_ship_id"
  end

  create_table "customers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.integer "has_good_credit"
    t.boolean "paid"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "harbours", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "country"
    t.string "lat"
    t.string "long"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "ships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "tonnage"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "addresses", "customers"
  add_foreign_key "cabins", "ships"
  add_foreign_key "credit_cards", "customers"
  add_foreign_key "cruises", "ships"
end
```

Essentially, I am just try to run the command: `rake ships:seed_cabins` and try to generate the data fresh. However, I keep getting the following error:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
/home/jonathon/Projects/waad/RailsApps/travelagent/lib/tasks/ships.rake:8:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'

Caused by:
SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
/home/jonathon/Projects/waad/RailsApps/travelagent/lib/tasks/ships.rake:8:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
Tasks: TOP => ships:seed_cabins
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am aware the order of when the tables are destroyed is an issue and the current order is the closest I can get to the file working. it seems to be the `Ship.destroy_all` line that is the issue because when I remove it and run the file it runs with no issues!

However, as far as I can see there would be no constraints left on that database once the other tables are cleared that would prevent `Ship` from being deleted?

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed destroying the cabins, which are still referencing the ships as foreign key. Hence the foreign key constraint is kicking in.

On a side note, you can make your life easier by adding `dependent: :destroy` in your associations. For example, in your `Ship` model, you would add,

```
class Ship < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cabins, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Since a cabin doesn't make sense without the corresponding ship. What this will do is, whenever a Ship instance is destroyed, it will destroy the related cabins as well.